# Distinct permutation subset rank and unrank in Delphi

Tags: delphi, subset, distinct, permutation, rank

Greetings Delphian stackers.

I've searched through out the site, all the "permutation rank & unrank" related discussions and could not find the one that meets my needs.

In Delphi:

Having an array of:

```
Members: array [0..3] of Byte = (0,1,2,3);
```

If one want's to iterate through all distinct permutations composed by 3 elements, one can estimate that the result list will be composed by 24 lines, lexicographically ordered as:

```
0   012
1   013
2   021
3   023
4   031
5   032
6   102
7   103
8   120
9   123
10  130
11  132
12  201
13  203
14  210
15  213
16  230
17  231
18  301
19  302
20  310
21  312
22  320
23  321
```

One can calculate the size of the list by using a "n choose k" formula, where "n" stands for the number of members and "k" for the number of choices:

```
p(n,k) = n! / (n-k)!
p(4,3) = 4! / (4-3)! = (4 x 3 x 2 x 1) / (1 x 1) = 24
```

What i'm trying to figure out is how to, (without searching through the entire list):

By supplying the lexicographic rank, let's say "13", one can "unrank" and obtain the subset "203".

By supplying the subset "203" one can obtain the lexicographic rank "13".

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Wait, you already have calculated all the n-permutations in a given space with k groups. Why would you need to iterate a list the results when you can already obtain the result with the formula? By the way, you are looking for a TDictionary in which the KEY is the number (13) and the VALUE is 203. I would use this!

Comment: Greetings Alberto, i'll be using this with very large spaces, only to extract a few subsets on certain conditions, i cannot afford several terabytes of db to search for a specific Index (Rank) or SubSet (UnRank).

Comment: A TDictionary<Integer, Integer> would help, it is an O(1) in terms of lookup speed. Can http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Tokyo/en/Generics_Collections_TDictionary_(Delphi) help?

Comment: It's not a matter of speed Alberto, space, it would generate an huge amount of disk/memory space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This combinatorial object has special name denoting "arrangement" in Russian and French combinatorics `A(n, k)`. It is easy to see that every digit occupies the first place of arrangement list `A(n-1, k-1)` times. So we can find what digit goes first for given rank and vice-versa - having the first digit, we can find interval of rank. Then continue for the next digits, removing used digits from the list.

```
function ArrangementByRank(n, k, rank: Integer): string;

    function NumArrNK(n, k: Integer): Int64;
    var
      i: Integer;
    begin
      Result := 1;
      for i := 0 to k - 1 do
        Result := Result * (n - i);
    end;

  var
    Dig: array of Byte;
    i, j, id, ank: Integer;
  begin
    Result := '';
    SetLength(Dig, n);
    for i := 0 to n - 1 do
       Dig[i] := i;  //initial digit list

    for i := 1 to k do begin
      ank := NumArrNK(n - i, k - i);  //might be optimized
      id := rank div ank;
      rank := rank mod ank;   //prepare for the next round
      Result := Result + IntToStr(Dig[id]);
      for j := id to n - i - 1 do
        Dig[j] := Dig[j + 1];  //squeeze digit list
    end;
  end;
```

Call with arguments `5, 3, 15` returns arrangement `1,2,0`. For reverse task  rank might be found as

```
 (Index of 1 in initial list) * A(4,2) + (Index of 2 in squeezed list) * A(3,1) = 
 1 * A(4,2)  + 1 * A(3,1) = 
 12 + 3 =
 15
```

Comment: Greetings MBo, and many thanks for putting me on the right track, of course your code can be optimized, but still, it's beautifully explained.